# @DeclareMixin with Spring AOP?

Tags: java, aop, mixins, spring-aop

Is it possible to use @DeclareMixin with Spring AOP? Or do they only support @DeclareParents?

I want to write an aspect that mixes in the java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport into a java bean:

```
public class PropertyChangeSupportWithInterface extends PropertyChangeSupport
    implements IObservableBean {

  public PropertyChangeSupportWithInterface(Object sourceBean) {
    super(sourceBean);
  }    
}
```

(IObservableBean simply contains all public methods from the PropertyChangeSupport)

```
@Aspect
@Named
public class ObservableAspect{
    @DeclareMixin("@ObservableBean *")
    public static IObservableBean createDelegate(Object object) {
      return new PropertyChangeSupportWithInterface(object);
    }
}
```

It seems that this aspect is never used, which makes me think that the @DeclareMixin is not supported by the runtime weaving done by Spring AOP.

Is there any way to get this working with Spring AOP?

You can find a (not) running example here (Maven multi module project):

https://github.com/BernhardBln/SpringAOPObservableBean

See the (only) test case in the springaop-observable-bean-aspect submodule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not supported by Spring AOP out the box. I see two options:

- Create a `DeclareMixinIntroductionInterceptor` for Spring AOP.
- Switch to Aspectj

I think that `PropertyChange` interface fits better in Aspectj because usually you will create a lot of proxies for prototype beans and them could be created easily out of the framework, by an ORM for example.

**Edit**

However I'm interested in this feature too and I already done some work for use it:

- A [DelegateFactoryIntroductionInterceptor](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop/src/main/java/org/jdal/aop/DelegateFactoryIntroductionInterceptor.java) to support creating delegates from the aspect instance.
- A [DeclareMixinAdvisor](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop/src/main/java/org/jdal/aop/DeclareMixinAdvisor.java) to join the inteceptor with the type pattern.
- A [DeclareMixinAspectJAdvisorFactory](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop/src/main/java/org/jdal/aop/DeclareMixinAspectJAdvisorFactory.java) to support the `DeclareMixin` annotation.

To use it you only need to declare a bean of type [DeclareMixinAutoProxyCreatorConfigurer](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop/src/main/java/org/jdal/aop/DeclareMixinAutoProxyCreatorConfigurer.java)
for configuring the `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` with the `AdvisorFactory` above.

I'm just testing, but seem that work fine.

Comment: Hey Jose, many thanks for your code! But how do I use the interceptor in Spring? I'm using annotation-based processing. Or can that only be done through xml?